# How to $and two documents in mongodb and Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb with Java 3.0 driver. I have a scenario where I have to perform logical and i.e, `$and` on my queries. For example, I have two documents already created and I am trying to do something like this:

```
iterable = mongoDatabase.getCollection("restaurants").find(
                                              new Document("$and", asList(abc,
                                                     updatedDocumentTypeOne)));
```

where `abc` is one document and `updatedDocumentTypeOne` is another document. I found this in mongodb manual but I am getting error as first create asList Method.

Or how to replicate the following in Java:

```
db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
} )`
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also try the code below that adds a filter for query replication in Java:

```
// Where db is the object reference of "inventory" collection's database
 MongoCollection<Document> inventory = db.getCollection("inventory");

//List for result return
 List<Document> result = new ArrayList<Document>();

//Query replication in Java and return result into the list
 inventory.find(Filters.and(
            Filters.or(Filters.eq("price", 0.99),Filters.eq("price", "1.99")),
            Filters.or(Filters.eq("sale", true),Filters.lt("qty", 20))
            )).into(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change from asList() to **Arrays.asList()**

Instead of writing Arrays.asList(), you have specified as asList(). So  compiler is searching for the method asList(), which is NOT available.

Check the below code :

```
iterable = mongoDatabase.getCollection("restaurants").find(
                                                new Document("$and", Arrays.asList(abc,
                                                        updatedDocumentTypeOne)));
```

For your above query, You can code as below :

```
/* First OR condition */
Document price1 = new BasicDBObject("price",0.99);
Document price2 = new BasicDBObject("price",1.99);

BasicDBList or_first = new BasicDBList();
or_first.add(price1);
or_first.add(price2);
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or_first);

/* Second OR condition */
boolean val = true;
Document sale = new BasicDBObject("sale",val);
Document qty = new BasicDBObject("qty", new BasicDocument("$lt",20));

BasicDBList or_second = new BasicDBList();
or_second.add(sale);
or_second.add(qty);
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or_second);

/* AND condition logic */
BasicDBList and_op = new BasicDBList();
and_op.add(or_first);
and_op.add(or_second);

iterable = mongoDatabase.getCollection("restaurants").find( new Document("$and", and_op ));
```

Comment: Its not working for me, and am using MongoDB java driver 3.0